# How to have a dialog box displayed automatically when a page is reached without having to click the link?

Tags: 8, modal-dialogs

Using Dialog API and advice from @leymannx, I added this link to a node (node99):

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:600}" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/27">Last minute information</a>
```

and it works fine: when clicked, the dialog box shows up!

Now, I'd like to have the dialog box displayed automatically when the node is reached without having to click the link.
@No Sssweat suggested to `make jQuery to click the link for you on page load $(".use-ajax").click();`

After some errors (`$ is not a function`), I finally used this:

```
(function ($) {
  $('.use-ajax').trigger("click");
})(jQuery);
```

It works but not as expected: the node 27 (the link has `href="/node/27"`) is displayed instead of node99, not in a modal over node99.
What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add an id and target with it, maybe `use-ajax` class used else where, add `id="my-dialog-modal"` and in the js change it to `$('#my-dialog-modal').trigger("click");`

Comment: Nothing better. Even worse: I don't have anymore node27 replacing node99. And when I go back to previous version - with `$('.use-ajax')`, same result: I'm stuck on node99. I'm confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS needs to be formatted like this:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myThemeBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.use-ajax', context).once('auto-open').each(function () {
        $(this).click();
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Your library needs to be defined like this:

```
example:
  js:
    js/example.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery #Just ot be save
    - core/drupal.dialog.ajax #Required for dialogs
```